# How can I populate an ArrayList<Integer> from a method?

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea

I'm trying to populate an `ArrayList<Integer>` with numbers. When I call on the method in the main method, the compiler complains that

```
Exception in thread "main"` 

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PrimeSum.setGeneralArray(PrimeSum.java:11)
        at PrimeSum.main(PrimeSum.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This a sample of my code.

```
public class PrimeSum {
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray;
private int limit;
public void setGeneralArray() {
    for(int i = 2; i < 2000001; i++) {
        generalArray.add(i);
    }
}
// ...
// This is how I call on the method.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrimeSum ps = new PrimeSum();
    ps.setGeneralArray();
    // ...
```

What's the thing I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance field `generalArray` is still `null` when you invoke `add`.

You need to initialize it before you populate it.

Either upon declaration:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Or in the constructor:

```
public PrimeSum() {
    generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Or in an instance statement:

```
{
    generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the ArrayList, my friend.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Best way to do it is intialize it in a constructor.

```
public class PrimeSum {
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray;
private int limit;
public PrimeSum(){
    generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
public void setGeneralArray() {
    for(int i = 2; i < 2000001; i++) {
        generalArray.add(i);
    }
}
...
//This is how I call on the method.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrimeSum ps = new PrimeSum();
    ps.setGeneralArray();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization, is missing for the array:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Without this, the `generalArray` is `null` (thus the `NullPointerException`).

```
private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray;
public PrimeSum(){
    generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`generalArray` is a *reference* type, its initial value is `null`, that's what the [JLS **4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) states:

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is `null`.

```
ReferenceType:
    ClassOrInterfaceType
    TypeVariable
    ArrayType
```

To initialize it, you should use the `new` keyword and call the constructor that matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the Objects in java is initialised to null and you are trying to say `null.add(number)` and hence you are getting null pointer exception. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for details. You need to initialize it. You could do it either directly in the class itself

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

or you could initialize it in constructor which is called whenever you create an object of type PrimeSum as you do in main like `PrimeSum ps = new PrimeSum();`. You could do it as below:

```
 public PrimeSum () {
     generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a arraylist of integers

```
   ArrayList<Integer> generalArray = new ArrayList<Integer>
```

for add item in list 
do this:

```
   generalArray.add(1);
   generalArray.add(2);
   generalArray.add(3);
```